# bash script works in terminal, not as expected from Mutt (macro)

Tags: macos, bash, macros, mutt, pbcopy

#### EDIT: Im not sure why it wasn't working before, but its working fine now.

- I added an `&` (to background the script)and `<enter>` at the end of the macro also, but it works with out it

I would like to copy a password from my OS X keychain into my clipboard. Then clear the clipboard after 7 seconds (from a Mutt macro)
This works from my terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

#copy password to clipboard
security find-generic-password -w -l "gpg-lil" |pbcopy
sleep 7
#clear clipboard
pbcopy<<<""
```

doesn't work when called from mutt (the clipboard gets the password, but never clears)
this is the Mutt macro:

```
#macro generic ,g "<shell-escape>$HOME/.mutt/gpg.sh"
#EDIT: below
macro generic ,g "<shell-escape>$HOME/.mutt/gpg.sh&<enter>"
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see comments:
works fine now 
I was editing in more than one terminal. I Think that is what was causing the weird behavior